# Why same request for hundreds times in access log

Tags: .htaccess, log-files

I don't know what comes to this, and how to prevent it. Look at the time, it keep on with the same request for hundreds times. Not just those particular IPs but some others too. How do I prevent this. Thanks in advance.

```
...
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:17 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51456 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:17 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51486 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:18 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51442 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:19 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51450 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:20 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51440 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:21 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51470 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:21 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51501 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:22 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51435 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:23 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51496 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:23 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51570 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
113.172.1.79 - - [29/Mar/2015:08:23:24 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51549 "http://http.vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; ARM; Touch; WPDesktop)"
...
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:18 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52323 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:20 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52358 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:22 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52436 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:26 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52340 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:29 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52409 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:30 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52310 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:31 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52364 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:32 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52208 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:34 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52336 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
171.253.16.62 - - [29/Mar/2015:14:13:37 +0000] "GET /bb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52336 "http://vietditru.com/bb/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53"
...
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:46 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:47 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:48 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:48 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:49 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:50 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:51 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:52 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:52 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:53 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:54 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:55 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
116.118.67.118 - - [29/Mar/2015:17:07:56 +0000] "GET /bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972 HTTP/1.1" 200 58917 "http://vietditru.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=571972" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
...
```

Comment: I think you might have a redirect issue on your site causing users to keep redirecting to the same page and then finally the browser prevents it after 10 requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that someone (or set of someones) is either scraping your site (badly), or has their page on refresh. You can work around this either by blocking their IP address, or, if you don't mind, just caching the page so it effectively costs your server nothing.

You can do this through the use of "Cache-control:" header.

Comment: Thanks. I just read this article [Cache-control](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) and vaguely understand. So where do I implement the control? I also use CloudFlare, is there way to put it there?

Comment: If you're using cloudflare, it's doing all the caching for you, so don't worry. If you want to implement it on your own, you do it through your webserver - what are you using?

Comment: Blocking the IP addresses would not work since there'll always be new IP. I did at the CloudFare but it seems it does not work, then I put a header statement at the beginning of the php script; it does not work either. Now I just put it in the Apache webserver and waiting. Two things, I am not sure that I did it correctly; secondly I used hurl.it to check if the header would change. It does not. Any suggestions?

Comment: To be clear, you did this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control